# Server culture:The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sqldatareader

I've recently moved a website from one windows server to a new 2016 box. Everything seems fine apart from one part of the site that is running a sql query but erroring on reading the result of this query into a datareader. If i take the sql being sent by the app to sql server (using profiler) i can run it in SSMS fine, but if i debug the line where the sql is executed in visual studio i see this error:

> "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value."

Now i can see the app passes some dates in this format '1998/08/31', could there be a culture setting in IIS/SQL which might cause a problem?

Comment: Yes the dateformat can cause this to happen. If you remove the backslashes then it would be dateformat independent.

Comment: Or, more ideally, convert the string into a `DateTime` as early as possible from the point where it's been input. Keep it in `DateTime` (or `datetime`) variables/parameters throughout its journey from UI towards the database. Trust ADO.Net to translate between the .NET and SQL Server data types. Avoid letting it be put in a string again and you *avoid* string conversion errors.

Comment: convert string result of that field into `datetime` on retrieval or use as string. But keeping dates as string in DB is a very bad thing to do. You're saying *"app passes"* - make app pass new `DateTime(year,month, day)` and you of course do know how to parse  `1998/08/31` to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

The best ways to **avoid this error** are in Sean Lange & Damien_The_Unbeliever's comments.

**You should do that.**

---

To answer your question:

> could there be a culture setting in IIS/SQL which might cause a problem?

Yes.

Sql Server's `dateformat` is implicitly set by the language setting. You can see the default settings for each language by querying `sys.syslanguages`, the default date format for each language is in the `dateformat` column.

```
select * from sys.syslanguages;
```

You can explicitly set a sessions date format with `set dateformat ymd;` or the sessions language with `set language us_english;`.

- [set dateformat {};](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx)
- [set language {};](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174398.aspx)
- [sys.syslanguages on rextester](http://rextester.com/JLV96914)